# Colocar botões de media social no site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

Estou "brincando" com o SPA MVC(C#) e gostaria de saber como eu coloco os botões das medias sociais no meu site. Procurei alguns exemplos aqui no site e pela minha consulta, não encontrei nada que me satisfizesse. Outra coisa é que os exemplos que pego na net, sempre vêm apontando para outros sites. Gostaria de fazer as coisas, mas sem apontar para ambientes externos, pois alguns lugares não permitem isso e é uma falha de segurança, como esse abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>   
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="www.devmedia.com.br" data-text="Teste" data-count="horizontal" data-via="aqui-seu-nome-de-usuario-do-twitter" data-lang="pt">twitter</a>
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais claro em sua pergunta? Você quer os botões de que ação? Qual rede social? O que você quis dizer com "Gostaria de fazer as coisas, mas sem apontar para ambientes externos, pois alguns lugares não permitem isso e é uma falha de segurança"?

Comment: @Randrade, é colocar aqueles botões de acesso ao Facebook, Twitter e etc.

Answer (score 2):

Navegadores modernos possuem restrições na hora de baixar arquivos JS de outras fontes. Você pode salvar o arquivo na sua solução e usar desta forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/widgets.js")"></script>   
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="www.devmedia.com.br" data-text="Teste" data-count="horizontal" data-via="aqui-seu-nome-de-usuario-do-twitter" data-lang="pt">twitter</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo utilizando [Fonte Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) e [Bootstrap Social](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/):

```
<p>
    Exemplo 1:
    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
</p>

<p>
    Exemplo 2:
    <div class="col-sm-4 social-buttons">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-github" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'btn-social', 'click', 'btn-github']);">
        <span class="fa fa-github"></span> Exemplo GitHub</a>

        <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'btn-social', 'click', 'btn-linkedin']);">
        <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span> Exemplo LinkedIn</a>
    </div>
</p>
```

[Veja funcionando no Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/oomqrggh/)

### No ASP.NET MVC

Lembre que o ideal é baixar os fonte do `CSS` e `JS` necessários. Os que utilizei estão no Fiddle e você pode copiar de lá se quiser.

No seu projeto `ASP.NET MVC` você pode chamar eles no `Bundle` assim:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
      "~/Content/bootstrap-social.css",
      "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css"));
```

Na sua `View`, basta chamar assim (no `head` do `HTML` de preferência):

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Comment: George, não sei o que está errado, mas não funcionou comigo. No BundlesConfig, coloquei as linhas para compilar o Bundles. Na View _Layout.cshtml, coloquei o parágrafos acima e o Style.Render que já existia. E não foi

Comment: @pnet Você pegou os arquivos `CSS` e colocou no seu diretório Content do projeto?

Comment: sim, fiz isso. Só consegui copiar assim, abri selecionei tudo, copiei e depois abri o Notepad++ e colei e salvei com o mesmo nome. Não havia opção para baixar diretamente do site(fiddle)

Comment: Dessa forma funciona, desde que salve como `CSS` não há problema. Mas note que você também pode usar o `Nuget` pra baixar esses pacotes, é mais recomendado (nele você terá todas as dependências). Quando rodar seu projeto use o `F12` pra ver se está dando erro para renderizar algum `script`.

Comment: Eu quando voltar, eu vou testar novamente. Desde já, obrigado.